# Getting error code: 1006 when running nativescript-actioncable with ios

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nativescript, actioncable

I am testing actioncable and nativescript and getting the error above. I've setup the test apps on my github.

One for [ActionCable](https://github.com/tedma4/websocket_api_test) and for [Nativescript](https://github.com/tedma4/websocket_ios_test)

The nativescript app is from the [nativescript-actioncable](https://github.com/sacketty/nativescript-actioncable) package. This only happens on iOS, Android connects fine.

I can't find any info on this problem and it's driving me crazy. Any help would be amazing.

Here are the console outputs:

Rails console:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-06 16:24:50 -0700
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-06 16:24:50 -0700
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-06 16:24:50 -0700
```

Nativescript console:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] ConnectionMonitor reopening 1491521019978
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] Reopening WebSocket, current state is closed 1491521019978
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js:46:33: [ActionCable] Opening WebSocket, current state is closed, subprotocols: actioncable-v1-json,actioncable-unsupported 1491521019978
```

Comment: having this same error

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and fixed by replacing [actioncable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-actioncable) plugin with [nativescript-websockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-websockets) and writing code for communication with actioncable server myself.

Here is the sample code that I have used

```
this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.8.104:3000/cable', []);
this.socket.on('open', function(evt) {
    console.log("Hey I'm open");
     var identifier = JSON.stringify({"channel": "ConversationsChannel"});
     var data = {"command": "subscribe", "identifier": identifier};
     var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    evt.target.send(payload);
});
this.socket.on('message', function(socket, message) {console.log("Got a message", message);});
this.socket.on('close', function(socket, code, reason) { console.log("Socket was closed because: ", reason, " code: ", code); });
this.socket.on('error', function(socket, error) { console.log("Socket had an error", error);});
```

and to send message

```
public sendMessage() {
        // "{"command":"message","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ConversationsChannel\",\"conversation_id\":\"12\"}","data":"{\"message\":\"ssss\",\"conversation_id\":\"12\",\"user_id\":39,\"action\":\"send_message\"}"}"
         var data = JSON.stringify({"message": "ssss","conversation_id":"12","user_id":39,"action":"send_message"});
         var identifier = JSON.stringify({"channel": "ConversationsChannel"});
         var payload = JSON.stringify({"command": "message", "identifier": identifier, "data": data});
         this.socket.send(payload);
    }
```

Similarly you can write unsubscribe that send payload

```
"{"command":"unsubscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ConversationsChannel\",\"conversation_id\":\"12\"}"}"
```

Or you can just go to node_modules/nativescript-actioncable/lib/action_cable.js and change line 240 from this

```
this.webSocket = new WS(this.consumer.url, {protocols: protocols, headers: headers});
```

to this

```
this.webSocket = new WS(this.consumer.url, {protocols: ["actioncable-v1-json"], headers: headers});
```

I hope this gives you an idea, let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The error 1006 indicates that the client part was terminated due to some error, so it is probably an issue related to the plugin. Perhaps you can verify that the plugin works at all (e.g. testing it with another service [this](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html))?

Comment: Yea. I'm pretty sure now that the problem is somewhere in the dependency, [nativescript-websocket](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-websockets).